# How to set the content of div to be visible inside parent div using css

Tags: css, reactjs

i want the content inside the expandable_container div to be visible.
Now it moves up while adding align-items: center to the expandable div.

I have a side panel which contains list items. when the list item overflows i add a expand button. clicking that button should show the full content of list item. It works but then. when the content in list item overflows then the content in list item is half seen. like in below image

[image]

i want that content to properly placed. I tried adding padding-top to expandable class. However this will affect other list items that doesnt have expandable component. How can i fix this. Below is the code,

```
export default class Expandable extends React.PureComponent{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.expandable_ref = React.createRef();
        this.state = {
            expanded: false,
            overflow: false,
        };
     }

     componentDidMount () {
         if (this.expandable_ref.current.offsetHeight < 
             this.expandable_ref.current.scrollHeight) {
             this.setState({overflow: true});
         }
     }

     on_expand = () => {
         this.setState({expanded: true});
         console.log("in expnad");
     };

     on_collapse = () => {
         this.setState({expanded: false});
     };

     render () {
         return (
             <div className={(this.state.overflow ? 
                 this.props.container_classname : '')}>
                 <div className={(this.state.overflow ? 
                 this.props.classname : '')} style={{overflow: 'hidden', 
                 display: 'flex', height: (this.state.expanded ? null : 
                 this.props.base_height)}}
                 ref={this.expandable_ref}>
                    {this.props.children}
                 </div>
                 {this.state.overflow && this.state.expanded &&
                     <div className={this.props.expand}>
                         <button  onClick={this.on_collapse}> 
                             {this.props.arrow_up}</button>
                     </div>}
                 {this.state.overflow && !this.state.expanded &&
                     <div className={this.props.expand}>
                         <button onClick={this.on_expand}> 
                             {this.props.arrow_down}</button>
                     </div>}

            </div>
        );
    } 
}

Class SidePanel extends React.purecomponent {
    switch (notification.type) {
        case 'new_model_uploaded':
            return (
                <Expandable
                     base_height={42}
                     arrow_down={<SvgAccDown className='grey' width="10" 
                     height="10"/>}
                     arrow_up={<SvgAccUp className='grey' width="26" 
                     height="26"/>}
                     container_classname='expandable_container'
                     classname='expandable'
                     expand='expand'>
                     <ListItem
                         icon={<SvgProject width="26" height="26"/>}
                         text={<Text
                         name={notification.initiator.name}
                         text=' created model '
                         model_name={notification.attributes.modelname}/>}
                         timestamp={notification.timestamp}>
                         <div className="additional_details">
                             <PreviewImage
                                 width={70}
                                 height={70}
                                 model_id={filtered_model.id}
                              />
                          </div>
                 </ListItem>
             </Expandable>
        );
    case 'deleted':
        return (
            <ListItem
                icon={<Svg width="20" height="22"/>}
                text={<Text
                name={notification.initiator.name}
                text=' deleted model '
                model_name={notification.attributes.modelname}/>}
                timestamp={notification.timestamp}/>
        );}

}

function ListItem(props) {
    return (
        <li className="notification">
            <div className="details_container">
                <div className="details">
                    {props.icon}
                    {props.text}
                    <Timestamp>{props.timestamp}</Timestamp>
                </div>
                {props.children}
            </div>
        </li>
    ); 
}


.notification {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 8px;
    min-height: 49px;
    flex-grow: 1;

    li {
        list-style: none;
    }

    .details_container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        flex-grow: 1;
        margin-right: 8px;

       .details {
            display: flex;
            color: #333;
            align-items: center;
            flex-grow: 1;

            svg {
                margin-right: 8px;
                margin-left: 7px;
                flex: 0 0 auto;
                align-self: center;
                flex-shrink: 0;
            }

            span {
                flex-grow: 5;
                text-align: left;
            }

           time {
               flex: 0 0 auto;
               margin-left: 8px;
               padding-top: 2px;
               color: #CCCCCC;
           }
        }

        .additional_details {
            flex-basis: 100%;
            width: 226px;
            margin-left: 11%;

            span {
                display: block;
                word-break: break-all;
                margin-left: 2px;
            }
        }
    }
}

.expandable_container {
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 8px;
    flex-direction: column;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC;

    .expandable {
        align-items: center;
        padding-top: 35px;
     }
}

.expand {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    width: 150px;
    height: 20px;
    left: 30%;
    background-color: $white;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Could someone help me solve this thanks.

Comment: please create snippet of the code

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**.